# Вывод результата скрипта Python в Laravel blade.php

Tags: python, laravel

помогите разобратся как правильно выводить результаты выполненного скрипта Python в Laravel blade.php. В данный момент результат скрипт работает и выводится нормально на экран, но я не могу понять как выводить его в DIV шаблона blade.php.

> web.php

```
Route::get('/verification', 'VerificationController@index')->name('up-menu/verification');

Route::get('/verification', 'VerificationController@testPythonScript')->name('up-menu/verification');
```

> verification.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title-block')
{{ __('Verification') }}
@endsection
@section('content')


<select>
  @foreach ($cat as $cats)
<option value=" {{$cats->Subategory}} ">{{$cats->Subategory}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>



@endsection
```

> VerificationController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

class VerificationController extends Controller
{

  public function testPythonScript()
{
    $process = new Process(array('python' , 'test.com/public/py/test.py'));
    $process->run();

    if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
        throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
    }

    echo $process->getOutput();

}

    public function index()
    {
        $cat=DB::table('Category')->get();

        return view('up-menu/verification')
        ->with('cat', $cat) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, вывод скрипта Python перенес в функци index, убрал роут функции testPythonScript, вывел через foreach в DIV.

> web.php

```
Route::get('/verification', 'VerificationController@index')->name('up-menu/verification');
```

> verification.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title-block')
{{ __('Verification') }}
@endsection
@section('content')


<select>
  @foreach ($cat as $cats)
<option value=" {{$cats->Subategory}} ">{{$cats->Subategory}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>

<div class="">
  @foreach ($process as $proce)
  {{$proce}}
  @endforeach
</div>

@endsection
```

> VerificationController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

class VerificationController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $cat=DB::table('Category')->get();


        $process = new Process(array('python' , 'test.com/public/py/test.py'));
        $process->run();

        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }
        $process->getOutput();


        return view('up-menu/verification')
        ->with('cat', $cat)
        ->with('process', $process);
    }
}
```